# How to reverse an array in angular js without creating a filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having an array in controller as follows

```
function FooController($scope) {
    $scope.items = ["a","b","c"];
}
```

I used ng-repeat to show the data in `items`,

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="FooController">
        <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
            <li>{{item}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I got the result as a,b,c order. I want to show it in reverse order. that means c,b,a **without changing its order in the controller** or **without creating a filter**. How to do that?
Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/agjqN/28/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to avoid the writting of a custom filter, I suggest you to use this syntax :

```
  <ul ng-repeat="item in items |  orderBy:'-toString()'">
```

The documentation assume you sort an array of Objects but in your case there are just plain strings.

Answer (score 17):

I faced the same problem, but with an array of objects. This quick solution worked for me, but using the filter is still the best practice.

```
<li data-ng-repeat="item in data.slice().reverse()">
      ...
</li>
```

http://bootply.com/SgVBZvZ708

Comment: reverse() is a native javascript function... why you consider this a "dirty solution"?

Comment: This looks cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the strings in objects and use orderBy or create a new filter:

```
angular.module("app",[])
.filter("reverse", function(){
    return function(items){
        return items.slice().reverse(); // Create a copy of the array and reverse the order of the items
    };
});
```

And use it like this:

```
 <ul ng-repeat="item in items|reverse">
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agjqN/29/) (I've also updated the ng-app directive so it's passed the "app" module.)

Comment: When I stored my `items` I used `items.slice().reverse();` now it's reversed pretty good.